# How can I prevent J-channel from directing water behind siding?

Tags: water, leak, siding, vinyl-siding

How do I redirect water to the gutter (as intended) and not behind the siding? Water is currently leaking behind the siding and exiting just below the gutter end cap. Gutter is clear, gutter pitch is good and gutter end cap seams are fully caulked.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really a matter of siding, but of *flashing*. Siding (especially vinyl) is poor at this job.

You want a kick flashing, like this. It should be installed first, then the siding added around it.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstructuretech.com%2Fkickout-flashing%2F&psig=AOvVaw0NXsr9SlWU5KPYFQ4GoPDi&ust=1690473876803000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQjhxqFwoTCLCW4IngrIADFQAAAAAdAAAAABAa)</sub>

Here's how it might look with vinyl. Note the extra piece of vinyl cut to flash over the kick:

[image: kick flashing vinyl example]

And an option with full channel:

[image]

Here's a good guide to [step and kick flashing](https://hammerandhand.com/best-practices/manual/6-roofs/6-1-kick-flashing/) provided by Edward.

<sub>[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.americanflashings.com%2Fjd-out-flashing&psig=AOvVaw0znbXRDChdkMRSbcb1myE-&ust=1690474166725000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQjhxqFwoTCPiXhJThrIADFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. So really a question of the j-channel, as this is an insufficient method of keeping the water from this location. In reviewing these instructions, the kicker flashing should install all the way up along the wall.
https://hammerandhand.com/best-practices/manual/6-roofs/6-1-kick-flashing/

Comment: I pulled the caulk from below the end-cap as well and can see to the backer board, which is soft and rotted of course. Sigh. This issue is bigger than the kicker, but the kicker needs to be installed as part of the fix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not exactly. "Step flashing" needs to be interleaved with each row of shingles all the way up the slope to work properly. The kicker is just the bottom bit.

Comment: Yeah, not a pleasant discovery. I'd look into a vinyl removal tool and plan to peel it all back from that area. It's not as painful as it sounds, though.

Comment: Is it just me or is that example picture wrong? Everything that runs down the siding and lands in the j-channel is going to just end up behind the siding where the J makes a step up before the kick. The kick should be installed behind the straight piece of J so it can push away water that runs down the inside of the J.

Comment: Found one that reflects how I've seen it installed before. They use a diagonal cut and an extra overlap in the siding, which I don't hate. Swapping it in now.

Comment: @KMJ it looks that way, but if you watch the video, he mentions how the water in the j-channel flushes into the kicker. https://youtu.be/0xu6i3pocz4?t=339